# mysql : avoid automatic cast of string in integer in where clause

Tags: mysql, casting

In my application, I use a generic where clause to search in different fields.

My request is like this :

```
SELECT * FROM command WHERE id = :search OR name LIKE %:search%;
```

I am searching the text "2SAV".
this request return some records where name contains "2SAV" (what I want) but also the record where id=2.

If I do more tests, I notice that :

```
SELECT CAST("2SAV" AS SIGNED); //2
SELECT 2="2SAV"; //1
```

If the string start with an integer, this part of string is kept.

Have you got an option or workaround to avoid this comportment?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the MySQL documentation( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html) is stated:

- In all other cases, the arguments are compared as floating-point (real) numbers.

I think you could cast in the query:

```
 SELECT * FROM command WHERE id = cast(:search as char) OR name LIKE %:search%;
```

Comment: Recast :search as char not work.
However, I can cast the id as char char and it work.
So the right request is : SELECT * FROM command WHERE CAST(id as char) = :search OR name LIKE %:search%;